# SingleStore (MemSQL) how to parse json field to column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, singlestore

I have a table source

| id | json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"some_id":{"some_text_1":"90","some_text_2":"50","some_text_3":"30"}} |
| 2 | {"some_id":{"some_text_3":"90","some_text_4":"50"}} |

I would like to get something like this

| text | value |
| --- | --- |
| "some_text_1" | 90 |
| "some_text_2" | 50 |
| "some_text_3" | 30 |
| "some_text_3" | 90 |
| "some_text_4" | 50 |

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use OPENJSON function in SQL Server. To transform the JSON data into the format you specified:

```
SELECT
    j.[key] AS [text],
    j.[value] AS [value]
FROM
    source s
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(s.json, '$.some_id') AS j
ORDER BY
    [text];
```

---

```
CROSS APPLY
    OPENJSON(s.json, '$.some_id') AS j
```

OPENJSON parses the JSON within the "some_id" property, creating a table-valued function that produces rows with the "key" and "value" columns.

To be able to use OPENJSON, ensure your database has a minimum compatibility level of 130.

If not you may see the following error:

```
Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'.
```

Then you need to do the following:

1/ Check the compatibility of your database:

```
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'DatabaseName';
```

2/ If it is not >= 130 then:

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 150;
```

---

Here is the result:

[image]

[image]